# Is it possible for a wrapped object to "become" an object of the same type?

Tags: c#, xml, object, wrapper, xmldocument

I have a wrapped XmlDocument class, and in it, I'd like to check to see if there's a cached XmlDocument object with the same name, and then "become" that object. Is there a better way to do this?

```
namespace myXmlUtilities {
  class SpecificAutoLoadingCmsXmlDocument : System.Xml.XmlDocument {
    private string documentName = "joiseyMike.xml";

    public void loadFromCms() {
        if (cache[documentName] != null) 
            LoadXml(((XmlDocument)cache[documentName]).OuterXml);
        else
            // ... load from the CMS's database.
    }

    public SpecificAutoLoadingCmsXmlDocument() {
        loadFromCms();
    }
  }
```

Edited: I made the example a little more true-to life. Apologies for the earlier quick-and-dirty version.

Comment: Why not make sure all the loading comes from a source with a cache? Why do you want it to act like an XmlDocument if you do the check on construction? Wouldn't it be better to check the cache prior to constructing any document object at all?

Comment: XmlDocument wraps XmlDocument? Eesh.

Comment: @Ryan: It's turtles all the way down.

Comment: @Skurmedel/Greg - this is just a quick and dirty example; I didn't cut and paste directly.

Comment: @Ryan: Yeah, that's part of the standards around here. Wrap everything and use the wrapper. Can't say I'm too fond of it.

Comment: It definitely makes more sense now, but still, I don't quite see what good this does :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a factory pattern instead which would allow you to put this logic into the factory method(s).

So you'd end up with:

```
public static XmlDocument GetNewDocument(string documentName) {
    if (cache[documentName] != null) 
        return cache[documentName];
    else
        return new XmlDocument();
}
```

So instead of doing a simple new XmlDocument();, you'd make a call to the static GetNewDocument() method.

Comment: Unfortunately that would require figuratively ripping the nervous system out of the app. But, I like it. I'm going to think about this a bit, and it might be the way to go.

Comment: I think you're going to have to rip it out otherwise you're going to get something very hacky and un-fun.

Comment: Your old team wrote the damn thing :)

Answer (score 2):

I would rework the arch here. You are missing a seperation of concerns. Why not use a factory to check if the cache has that name and give you that object back? An object trying to construct itself seems messy to me.